# XBee Pro Rx pin 4V tolerant

Tags: xbee

I'd like to know if I could directly plug a 0-4 V Tx pin to the Rx pin of an Xbee Pro, serie 1. I've always seen the datasheet, and I can't find there whether this voltage is tolerates or not.

Comment: Where is the datasheet?

Comment: [Here](http://www.digi.com/pdf/ds_xbeemultipointmodules.pdf)

Comment: It's not a datasheet, it's a promotional brochure. [This](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Datasheet.pdf) is datasheet.

Comment: Sorry, I trusted the website (it says "product data sheet"... ), but didn't downloaded it again. Nonetheless, I searched in the datasheet, not in this brochure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Digi Knowledge base](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Interfacing-Digi-OEM-RF-Modules-to-Microcontrollers) is explicitly stating:

> To be clear, the inputs to the XBee module are NOT 5V tolerant and
>   cannot accept a voltage level higher than 3.3v on any pin. Applying a
>   voltage higher than 3.3V will damage the module and void your
>   warranty. However, the following modules operate at 5V or are 5V
>   tolerant: XCite, XStream, XTend, XBee XSC (S3 Only)